# Creating FLACs: maximizing sound levels

Tags: levels, encoding, flac, cd

I want to experiment with FLAC to see if my aging ears can tell the difference between that and highest-quality MP3.  I have been using AudioGrabber for mp3, which does its encoding via LAME.  A feature of this program is that you can set it to scale the recording level such that the peak is at a given level, by default 98%.

I have not looked into CD to FLAC much, beyond using MediaMonkey5. It faithfully reproduces the sound image.  In the case of The Beatles Red Album (2023 release), for example, the maximum sound level is -8db.  There is no option for scaling the level to near maximum.

One could argue that scaling a CD means it is no longer a duplicate, and that's true.  And scaling potentially introduces a distortion of a maximum of 1/65532 for 16-bit samples.

The flip side is that scaling gives a wider dynamic range for the DAC to work with. From the point at which it exits DAC as an analog signal, this should mean a reduced signal-to-noise ratio, since each analog stage adds some noise.  Albums, which vary considerably in their digital recording levels, are more consistent in volume.  Yes, there is level post processing to help with that, but maybe it's better to start with leveled sound images.

I like Audiograbber, but it does not offer FLAC, and probably never will.

Questions:

1. I'd like to hear your reaction to my reasoning.  Is there another downside to scaling that I am not seeing?
2. What CD to FLAC ripper do you like?  Are there any that offer scaling?
3. I am baffled as to why the CD mastering process does not use maximum levels.  You have 16 bits!  Why not use as much of the scale as you can?

Comment: A few minor comments: 1) You don't need to rip from CD directly to FLAC; there's more flexibility to rip to an uncompressed lossless format such as AIFF or WAV, and then convert that to FLAC separately.  2) 16 bits defines the maximum sample value, not the maximum sound level.  (I think most CDs aim to approach the maximum sample value.)  3) AIUI, you'd still get the same benefits if the FLAC stored exactly the values from the CD, and the player then scaled the sound during playback (e.g. using something like ReplayGain).

Comment: As an example, the newly remastered Beatles Red Album (2023).  When ripped to FLAC, the peak volume is about -8db.

I think it would be most convenient to go direct from CD to FLAC like I have done with MP3s: one step instead of two.  But what is your preferred WAV to FLAC converter, and is there one that will scale?

Comment: I simply use the command-line `flac` program — but I don't use FLAC for very much, so I don't do anything sophisticated.  (I make much more use of the `lame` program for encoding to MP3, as that's supposed to give the best quality when configured appropriately — more important with a lossy codec.)  I'm not sure what you mean by ‘scale’, but if you're running it from a shell or a script, then you can of course run multiple instances in parallel.